# Dynamically add accessor methods in Laravel Model Class

Tags: laravel

I've got the function names constructed however I want in an array which are dynamic in nature meaning they could be 2 or 10 like so:

[image]

#### Result

I want them to reside in model class (e.g: User) like this:

```
public function getEmailVerifiedAtAttribute($value)
{
  // ...
}

public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
  // ...
}

public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
{
  // ...
}

// ... If there were more in array they would have been constructed dynamically as well.
```

**If we can avoid the eval please!!**

Comment: is there a reason you can't just define these methods on this model? and why would `eval` come into play?

Comment: Yes because I'm developing a package and before head I can't know the fields with specific type the end user wants to alter in certain way.

Comment: you have an array of names for accessors but what would define what they are supposed to actually do? is there a reason they can't use their own model that they can alter as needed?

Comment: Definition would be same:  let's say the 
```
return ucwords($value);

Comment: you could have an array with just the attribute names and you could override `getAttribute` to check this array and handle those cases and if not call parent `getAttribute`, but i don't see why the end user couldn't define their own model how they wish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have some limited success by doing something like this in your model:

```
public function hasGetMutator($key) {
   return parent::hasGetMutator($key) || in_array('get'.Str::studly($key).'Attribute', $youArratOfDynamicMutators);
}

protected function mutateAttribute($key, $value)
{
        if (parent::hasGetMutator($key)) {
           return parent::mutateAttribute($key, $value);
        }
        // Mutate your value here
        return $value;
}
```

What this does is override the method `hasGetMutator` which usually just checks if the function `'get'.Str::studly($key).'Attribute'` exists in the class to also return true if that function name exists in your array, and also modifies the `mutateAttribute` function to do your custom mutation (in addition to doing the default ones).

However if your mutation is a standard one then I do recommend using a [custom cast](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts) instead:

```
<?php

namespace App\Casts;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\CastsAttributes;

class MyCustomCast implements CastsAttributes
{

    public function get($model, $key, $value, $attributes) {
        // Do the cast
        return $value;
    }

    //Optional
    public function set($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        // Reverse the cast 
        return $value;
    }
}
```

To get this to work for dynamic attributes you can add this to your model:

```
protected function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    $this->casts = array_merge($this->casts, [
        'customCastColumn1' => MyCustomCast::class,
         // ...
    ]);
}
```

This will add the required casts to the model when it gets constructed.

Comment: [code]
trait ConvertFields
{
    public function hasGetMutator($key)
    {
        dd('$vars');
        return $this->hasGetMutator($key)
          || in_array('get'.Str::studly($key).'Attribute',
            $this->getConvertionFields());
    }

    protected function mutateAttribute($key, $value)
    { 
        dd('$vars');
        if ($this->hasGetMutator($key)) {
            return $this->mutateAttribute($key, $value);
        }

        // Mutate your value here
        return $value . 'd';
    }
[code]

It never gets called, in IDE it shows it's been over-riden.

Comment: isn't hasGetMutator called automatically ??

Comment: The mutator will only get called when you try to access the attribute. For example if you do `$model->my_attribute` and there's no `my_attribute` in the actual database then the `hasGetMutator` will be called to look for function `getMyAttributeAttribute` . You can automatically append custom attributes by adding them to the `$appends` field in your model, which you can do in the constructor if you want it dynamic

Comment: The first option worked like a charm for me. When you took a gap b/w posting your last commit, I learned a lot :-), e.g: Laravel collections are now lazy, they don't call accessors/mutators until you access/update the attribute.